# SQL Server does not exist or Access Denied but works with udl

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, connection-string

I can connect to my instance of SQL Server via a udl file (test connection) but when I try to do the same via Powershell or a console application, I get the SQL Server does not exist or access denied error. I tried with and without the Integrated Security = SSPI to no avail

```
Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=\\PCNAME_XXX;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User Id=***;Password=***;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try DataSource=PCNAME_XXX (without "\\")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to PrfctByDsgn, the error was to use the \ in front of the name of the PC.
Thanks